# C++ Class in IOS App, Xcode 5

Tags: c++, ios, class, xcode5, objective-c++

I have an IOS app that is a single view application. It has a standard C++ class that I made in it, however, it is not accepting the cpp class. Here is a simplified version of the .h file(without those lines #s):

```
1 #ifndef __Calculator__Numbers__
2 #define __Calculator__Numbers__
3 #include <iostream>
4 class NumDigits
5 {
6 };
7 #endif
```

I get the error: `'iostream' file not found`

It appears as if the project doesn't have the C++ libraries? If this is it, how would I add them? If not, what should I do to fix this error?
It looks like the cpp libraries are not included in my project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TMm6.png

Comment: don't you accidentally `#import` your C++ header? Or you mean you only created the empty class and now building fails?

Comment: I `#include`d the C++ header. And yes the cpp class was an empty class, but it is filled with stuff, which I didn't post.

Comment: The issue is not about cpp libs not being included in the project. Could you try building with empty class?

Comment: the problem is most likely that your project has the file associated with an objective-c header. You can override this. Highlight the file and in the information pane (Right hand side) it will say "Default - C Header". This basically is causing clang to incorrectly parse the file. Change it to a c++ header. This should allow clang to recognize the cpp information.

Comment: That didn't seem to work. The file is still not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implementation files have the extension `.m` in Obj-C . To use a C++ file in your Xcode project with Objective-C you must use `.mm` extension and you can include C++ header in the `.mm` file. You mustn't include the header in `.m` file, but if you want to include your C++ header in `.h`, you will need a macro like:

```
#ifdef _CP
#include <iostream>
#endif
```

Comment: This is not a problem with a .m file. It is a problem with the cpp class header file.

Comment: @Obj-CPadawan Sorry, I think I hadn't explained it clearly. Check out the updated answer. I hope that helps.

Comment: That solves the error. Thanks. Although now there are new errors. The compiler won't accept `class NumDigits{};`. It says "class" should be "Class" and `Expected ';' after top level declarator` wants a ';' after `NumDigits` and before the '{'.

Comment: Now that I look at it again, the macro _CP is not defined, so the compiler skips over the `#include` and moves on. When the `#include <iostream>` is not there, the compiler gives off the errors in the above comment. When it sees that it cannot find iostream, it does not detect the errors mentioned above that are on on a line lower down. When `ifndef _CP` is put in, it cannot find the `iostream` file. I am not too great with macros, but _CP is not defined.

Comment: Hmm... I'm mibile at the moment. Will check it once I get to my Mac and keep you posted.

Comment: Well to solve the problem, I just took out everything in the cpp header and just left the function definitions and put private variables as globals in the .cpp. Then just #included the header in my .mm and called the functions of the cpp like a normal cpp program would. That fixed everything. I just had to include the libraries in the .cpp. The header only had `void myfunction (int a) ; int otherfunction () ; etc.`No more `class MyClass{public:private:}; `

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, I just took out all the macros, `#include`s, and class declarations:

```
#ifndef __Calculator__Numbers__
#define __Calculator__Numbers__
#include <iostream>
class NumDigits
{
};
#endif
```

and left only the function declarations: `void myFunction(int myVariable) ;`
Then in the .cpp:

```
#include <iostream> //and other #includes
void myFunction(int myVariable) {
//stuff
}
```

This worked because the functions were still called and values were passed to and from them. The return values were the values that should've been spit out. when in the `.mm` if the `.cpp` was `#included`, the iostream file couldn't be found so `3include the .h`,and in the `.cpp`, `#include` the `.h`